# How can I read data from MySQL in different project which is saved by another app?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I have two separate applications that are working with the same database in MYSQL. The first app in Nodejs and modify data in the database, when I want to read data from the second app coded in PHP, the data looks hidden (no result to select). I can see the data in the database, and I can get the result from the same query that I have in PHP. When I am adding data manually, it is accessible from PHP app.

Code in Node.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

const mysqlconnection = mysql.createConnection({
 host:'172.16.X.X',
 user:'XXX',
 password:'XXXX',
 database:'ramen'
 });

var sql = "INSERT INTO challenge_usersolved (user, challenge_Id, username) 
VALUES (?,?,?)";
var values = [challenge.name , challenge.difficulty, usname];
mysqlconnection.query(sql, values,(err, row)=>{

})
```

PHP side Code is:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('172.16.X.X', 'ramen', 'XXX', 'ramen', '3306');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 $query = "SELECT sum(challenge_Id)*100 as score, username FROM (SELECT 
 Distinct user, challenge_Id, username FROM challenge_usersolved) as T 
 GROUP BY username;";
 $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
 if (!$result) {
     echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . 
     mysql_error();
  }

  $rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo "<html><head><title>Score Board</title></head><body>";
echo "<table align='center' border='1px' style='width:300px; line-height: 30px'>";
echo"<tr><th colspan='2'>Students Score</th></tr><t><th>Username</th> <th>Score</th></t>";
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    echo "<tr><td>{$rows["username"]}</td><td>{$rows["score"]}</td></tr>";
}


echo "</body></html>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you see errors in the server logs? Is error logging turned on on your server?

Comment: @LajosArpad, unfortunately, I do not have access to logs, Just I am checking in the PHP side, and it looks there is no error. Is it possible to be the cause of the format of data is saving by Node.js?

Comment: If you run the SELECT sum(challenge_Id)*100 as score, username FROM (SELECT 
 Distinct user, challenge_Id, username FROM challenge_usersolved) as T 
 GROUP BY username; query directly in the database what do you get as a result?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes I can get the result that what I need

Comment: 100 | sareza
------------
100 | abcsd
-------------
This a sample that I can see in MYSQL. But with my code, I can see the second line because I entered manually.

Comment: Can you var_dump($result);? What do you see?

Comment: @LajosArpad there is a strange result for that. 
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
$rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

line loads the first record and you do not do anything with it. When your code arrives to the `while` loop, the next (second) row is attempted to be loaded, but you have a single row as you described in the comment section. The solution seems to be to remove the

```
$rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

line.